# Storing an Object into a temporary Object and not changing the original Objects value

Tags: java, variables

I have an object stored in a global variable let's say:

```
static ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

I want to store it later to look into it without actually changing the values in the structure itself. So I am doing something similar to this:

```
public void someMethod()
{
     ArrayList<Object> tempList = new ArrayList<Object>();
     tempList = list;
     list.remove(0);
}
```

I'm thinking this may have something to do with me initializing the variable as "static".  I don't usually do that but Eclipse told me I had to so I just let the change happen.

My understanding would be that I am storing the original list into a temporary list and anything I do to the temporary list would be independent of the original list.  But it appears that if I were to remove something from this above list, that the original list is removing it as well.

I remember learning that this could happen sometimes but I think I've done this before without having that issue.

I apologize if this is a repeated question but the way I worded it didn't show me an question that was similar.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My understanding would be that I am storing the original list into a temporary list and anything I do to the temporary list would be independent of the original list.

This is not the case. When you do something like

```
a = b;
```

then *both* `a` and `b` refer to the *same* object. Mutations in `a` show up in `b` and vice verse (since there is only a single object in question). In this case you probably want to use the [copy constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28java.util.Collection%29) of `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<Object> tempList = new ArrayList<Object>(list);
```

Notice that here we are explicitly creating a new, independent object and assigning *that* to `tempList`.

Note that this creates what's called a [shallow copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Shallow_copy): the objects referenced by the list themselves are not copied, but instead a new *list* is created that contains the references to the same objects as the original list.

Comment: +1 for creating a new list, although you should point out that it's a shallow copy, and that manipulation of any individual element will still show up in both lists.

Comment: I only used ArrayList as an example, what I am actually doing is creating a Linked Queue data structure myself and using it with Objects from an API.

Comment: I suppose I could add that constructor into my Linked Queue implementation.  I wouldn't be manipulating any element inside the Queue however, so does this mean your strategy would work?

Comment: I probably should have specified this, but what I'm doing is looking through the queue and comparing elements and dequeuing the elements to looking at the next element. (I know probably less efficient than just creating a better way to iterate through my queue

Comment: @GasperGulotta If you're not mutating any elements contained in the collection then you should be fine. If you have your own collection class, then yes it might be wise to add a similar copy constructor. You can look at `ArrayList`s source to see how they do it.

Comment: @arshajii I appreciate the assistance and patience. This helps alot!

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your `someMethod`, your `tempList` disappears into the dark void of the GC. If you want to keep it, you need to turn it into a similar field as `list` is.

Also, assigning `list` to `tempList` makes you have two references to the same object.

Comment: The GC doesn't come into play here. There's still a reference that exists to that `ArrayList` after the method exists.

Comment: Yes. This is the second issue in that code. He is trying to store a copy of the original list, but in a local variable, which will be dead after the end of the method. Issue #1. He also does not do a copy of the list, but of the reference to it. Issue #2.